# Python reading lines in nested for loops from two files

Tags: python, file, loops, line

I want to match the lines of one text file with another text file, line by line, there is a problem with my nested for loops, it must be simple, but I can't find it,

```
for line1 in ratings:
    cont1+=1

    for line2 in movies:
         cont2+=1
         print(cont1,cont2)
```

I simplified it with this loops, to check the error, 
The outer loop doesn't reach cont=2,

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
.
.
.
1 157
>>>
```

Comment: Your description and program seem to be at odds, this will produce every line from ``movies`` for every line from ``ratings`` - I think what you want is ``zip()`` or ``itertools.zip_longest()`` to match line 1 with line 1, line 2 with line 2, etc...

Comment: I didn't explain it very well, I'm sorry. My principal problem is that i don't understand why this nested loops that work fine on their own, and also work fine iterating two strings, why this doesn't work with to files, and get stucked the outer loop in index 1?

Comment: I would presume your file only has one line. Please give all of your code and the file contents, otherwise we can't say more.

Comment: The problem was that I need to reset the inner loop with seek(0), doing that the loop works properly, thanks to everyone for your replies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script skips second for loop when reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901909/script-skips-second-for-loop-when-reading-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I need to reset the inner loop with seek(0), doing that the loop works properly, thanks to everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 5):

you need to loop over both files simultaneously

```
ratings= open('ratings.txt')
movies= open('movies.txt')

for rating, movie in itertools.izip(ratings, movies):
    # do task
```

or

```
ratings= open('ratings.txt').readlines()
movies= open('movies.txt').readlines()

for rating, movie in zip(ratings, movies):
    # do task
```

Comment: why `itertools.zip`? which version of python is this?

Comment: Why use ``readlines()`` rather than iterating over the file? It makes using ``izip()`` pointless. Also this prosumes the files are the same length or you don't mind one being truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation runs for every line in file1 run all line in file2,

the actual code shd be,

```
for line1,line2 in zip(ratings,movies):
 cont1+=1
 cont2+=1
 print(cont1,cont2)
```

Comment: Presuming the files are the same length or you don't mind one being truncated.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('ratings.txt') as ratings, open('movies.txt') as movies:
    for rating, movie in itertools.izip(ratings, movies):
        # do task
```

This is an improvement on [avasal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13138004/36537) in that it picks up the lines iteratively (equivalent to the old `xreadlines` that is now deprecated) rather than reading all the lines in via `readlines()`. So it should read a line from each, then process them, then read another line etc, permitting Files Of Enormity where `readlines` implementation would be limited to smaller files.

Note that `izip` continues until one of the iterators stops, so you'll only get as many rows as the shorter file. I'm assuming that's correct, however, since the code implicitly assumes the two files match anyway.

Comment: Why have you made ``g_read()``? It does literally nothing. You should also use the ``with`` statement to open files.

Comment: @Lattyware: you have a point, I'd forgotten that the result of open was iterable. I also thought that `with` could only take 1 context, but apparently in 2.7.3 it can take multiple contexts as above. So, cheers.