# Python - How to loop through lines of multiple files

Tags: python, file

I have 2 files: `"a.txt"` and `"b.txt"` where I want to match lines between them. The files contain the following:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

To match the lines, I'm doing the following

```
    a = open("a.txt","r") 
    b = open("b.txt","r")
    for al in a:
        al = al.split()
        val_a = al[0]
        for bl in b:
            bl = bl.split()
            val_b = bl[0]
            print val_a, val_b
```

Surprisingly, the print statement `ONLY` prints the following:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
1 10
```

Which appears to be that the loop on a is only accessed once. What I tried for debugging is the following:

```
for al in a:
    al = al.split()
    val_a = al[0]
    print val_a
    for bl in b:
        bl = bl.split()
        val_b = bl[0]
```

The print statement here prints all the values within `a`

Can someone help me with a possible explanation?

Comment: A similar question is answered [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095855/whats-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-lines-of-multiple-files)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137969/python-reading-lines-in-nested-for-loops-from-two-files

Comment: I ended up using the "with" instead of the normal "open" statement which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to reset the file pointer to the start of the file for `b.txt` each time you attempt to loop through it, otherwise you've reached the end.

The easiest way to do this is with `file.seek(0)` as shown below:

```
a = open("a.txt","r") 
b = open("b.txt","r")
for al in a:
    al = al.split()
    val_a = al[0]

    b.seek(0)

    for bl in b:
        bl = bl.split()
        val_b = bl[0]
        print val_a, val_b
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch `b` to a list of lines with `readlines()`, and then you can iterate over it again and again:

```
a = open("a.txt","r") 
b = open("b.txt","r").readlines()
for al in a:
    al = al.split()
    val_a = al[0]
    for bl in b:
        bl = bl.split()
        val_b = bl[0]
        print val_a, val_b
```

Comment: Depending on the size it is even better to read the lines of b once and for all

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
a = open("a.txt","r")
b = open("b.txt","r")
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    print (i.split()[0])
    print (j.split()[0])
```

Explanation:

```
1)zip file will open both files simultanously
2)for loop will loop through line by line (i=one line in a-file, j=one line in b-file)
3)i.split()[0] will give first word/element of line
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert b as a list else first iteration through b will consume the file.

```
 blist= list(b)
```

Then the inner loop

```
For bl in blist:
 ...
```